# Controle de Permissão em c# e Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, permissões

Eu gostaria de criar em C# com Windows Forms ( basicamente igual de permissão de pasta do Windows), níveis de acesso para os usuários, mas não como nível 1, 2 e 3, mas sim por exemplo:

- Usuário A só pode visualizar um cadastro de cliente;
- Usuário B pode excluir e deletar;
- Usuário C pode visualizar só alguns campos do cadastro do cliente.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: oi Amigo, boa noite, recomendo as leituras
https://www.codeproject.com/kb/miscctrl/application_login.aspx
https://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/securebaseform.aspx

Comment: Muito complexo o que você quer para uma simples pergunta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve construir sua aplicação no formato "Baseada em Regras" (*role-based* em inglês).

Para isso, você pode fazer com que seus forms herdem alguns comportamentos específicos de controle acesso.

[Aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/42750/a-secure-role-based-windows-form) você encontra um tutorial detalhado de como fazer isso (em inglês).

Com tudo, esse tutorial não chega ao nível de campo (somente de formulários). Essa parte você precisará implementar "na mão" através da propriedade `Visible` dos componentes.

---

Uma outra forma de implementar é fazer o controle de acesso antes de abrir o form em si.
Normalmente utiliza-se um menu baseado em dados no banco de dados e esses dados podem definir se a opção do menu será exibida ou não.

Mas ainda assim, as permissões em nível de campo deverão ser implementadas manualmente.

---

*Setar* a propriedade `Visibile` para `false` pode acarretar em problemas de layout caso você não esteja utilizando classes específicas de layout (`containers`) no seu form.

Se ainda não utiliza, aconselho a leitura de [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) e [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1 - Uma tabela no banco com campos bool para guardar a permissão (um campo para cada item que você deseja alterar a permissão)
2 - Um objeto no seu sistema para receber os dados de permissão do banco;

3- Na inicialização do sistema ao logar você deve varrer os componentes setando o no componente.enable ou comente.visible o valor da permissão correspondente.